# Входит ли слово ЭТО в состав сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые

В учебнике русского языка Бабайцевой слова ЭТО, ЗНАЧИТ, ВОТ входят в состав сказуемого; на портале Грамота тоже есть фраза "Если в составе сказуемого есть указательные слова ЭТО, ВОТ или ЗНАЧИТ", позволяющая считать данные слова частью сказуемого. А где-то слово это не входит в состав сказуемого. Как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Указательная частица "это" в составном именном сказуемом по своей функции близка к связке. А связка вместе с именной частью образуют часть сказуемого. Это т. н. логическая связка, которая в отличие от глагола-связки *быть*, не выражает ни времени, ни наклонения, ни лица, ни числа, ни рода. Видимо, поэтому в некоторых учебниках об этой частице-связке ничего не говорится.
Среди специалистов, включающих частицу "это" в состав сказуемого, Н. С. Валгина, Н. М. Пипченко.

[Н. С. Валгина. Современный русский язык, СИНТАКСИС](http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/yanko.valgina_2003_416p_rasp_sl.htm#_Toc331393938)

[Н. М. Пипченко. СОВРЕМЕННЫЙ РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК. СИНТАКСИС СЛОВОСОЧЕТАНИЯ И ПРОСТОГО ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ](http://philology.bsu.by/documents/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%96%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%9E/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%BF%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%9C.%D0%9C/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A131%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C0%2C842%2Cnull%5D)

Comment: @ Римма Михайлова, спасибо за исправления! Сам не понял. откуда появились лишние слова.